# Last record of the same group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I think there are similar questions but none of them really matches my case. I tried left outer join to get the latest status but then I can't get the latest record based on the parent id grouping.

I have the following tables

Document table

| id | version name | parnet_id1 | parent_id2 | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UUI1 | A | 1 | 100 | timestamp1 |
| UUI2 | B | 1 | 100 | timestamp2 |
| UUI3 | C | 2 | 100 | timestamp3 |
| UUI4 | D | 2 | 100 | timestamp4 |
| UUI5 | E | 2 | 100 | timestamp5 |

Document history table

| document_id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UUI1 | Active | timestamp1 |
| UUI1 | Inactive | timestamp2 |
| UUI2 | InActive | timestamp3 |
| UUI2 | Active | timestamp4 |
| UUI3 | InActive | timestamp3 |
| UUI3 | Active | timestamp4 |
| UUI4 | InActive | timestamp3 |
| UUI4 | Active | timestamp4 |
| UUI5 | Active | timestamp3 |
| UUI5 | Inactive | timestamp4 |

What query gives me the following table
(group with parent_id1 and parent_id2)

**So docs that have the same parent_id1 and parent_id2 are different versions of the same doc so we only interested in the latest version based on timestamp.** We also need their latest status from the history table based on the timestamp (one to many)

| id | version name | parnet_id1 | parent_id2 | timestamp | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UUI2 | B | 1 | 100 | timestamp2 | Active |
| UUI5 | E | 2 | 100 | timestamp5 | Inactive |

Comment: I'm very unclear on what your sample data mean and what you're trying to do. Should timestamp5 appear in your Document history table somewhere? Maybe you can show us the query that you've tried and the results it produced, and then highlight how your desired results differ.

Comment: Oh I’m sorry for confusing you, time stamps are just insertion time so basically come from ‘now()’ function, I indexed them to show which one is older and which one is earlier

Comment: For the sake of demonstration

Comment: I need more arbitrary fields to be in the final result, I tried to add a field called `address` on the demo, I couldn't get it worked, can you take a look? or Answer here. ps. Ignore this comment. I get it working with extra fields. Let me try it on my real problem and get back here. Thanks

Comment: It is 99% what I want except the status is not coming as the latest record in the histories table. I think the problem is this part `as h3 on h2.document_id = h3.id and h3.created = h2.created` .

Comment: There should be some logic that makes sure we get the status from the most recently inserted record of that grouping from `document_histories` table, right?

Comment: Oh wait, I think it is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `inner join` and `group by` we can do it as follows :

```
select h3.*, h2.status
from history h2
inner join (
  select t.id, t.version_name, t.parnet_id1, t.parent_id2, max(h.timestamp) as timestamp
  from history h
  inner join (
    select d.id, d.version_name, d.parnet_id1, d.parent_id2
    from document d
    inner join (
      select parnet_id1, parent_id2, max(timestamp) as timestamp
      from document
      group by parnet_id1, parent_id2
    ) as s on s.parnet_id1 = d.parnet_id1 and s.parent_id2 = d.parent_id2 and s.timestamp = d.timestamp
  ) t on t.id = h.document_id
  group by t.id, t.version_name, t.parnet_id1, t.parent_id2
) as h3 on h2.document_id = h3.id and h3.timestamp = h2.timestamp
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zP0IfaXM)